# How to install Ruby on Red hat

Tags: ruby, linux, rhel

I'm trying to install **ruby** on **Red Hat**, via an *ssh-connection*, but it won't work.

I **can't** use `yum install ruby`, because I don't have the needed `repositories`.

Comment: http://www.redhat.com/magazine/025nov06/features/ruby/

Comment: Best thing is, to use a ruby versions manager like http://rvm.io/

Comment: Is adding a repository an option?

Comment: @ Chris Wesseling: It would be, if I'd know, where to get it.

Comment: @hizbul25: You allready got me forward, but when I try the third step, {./configure}, I get 

{[root@rh0045 ruby-2.1.0]# ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/root/ruby-2.1.0/ruby-2.1.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details}

Answer (score 2):

I have three options for you:

1) You can install it from sources.

First of all you'll need to install some build tools and libraries.
On Centos/RedHat the easiest way to do it is using `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`.

If this doesn't work you'll need to run at least: `yum install gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison iconv-devel` the bare minimum to build. Eventually is you have no internet access and just ssh you can SCP the single packages from your machine.

Once installed build tools , if you have internet access on those machines, I suggest also to install RVM to make less painful upgrade and not have to mess around with path definition for the new libraries and binaries.

To install it is quite simple `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` will do the trick and after a `rvm install <version>` will permit you to install (for this user) any ruby version you want and create gemset without touch the system.

Be aware that installing new gems that need to be build will require to install other devel libraries if they have compiled extensions.

Have also a look to http://rvm.io/rubies/installing for more references about rvm use

Otherwise you can use @hizbul25 tutorial to install std ruby from source.

2) You can use omnibus, https://github.com/opscode/omnibus-ruby, is the package useb by Opscode, Mcollective and other tools to create a selfcontaines VirtualEnvironment for specific application.

You can select the gem and the ruby version you need and it will create a tgz with all you need to run ruby scripts. 
This tgz can be uncompressed where you want (ex: /opt/omnibusruby/) and you'll need just to point the shebangs of your scripts to `#!/opt/omnybusruby/embedded/ruby-2/bin/ruby` or create a an alias `/usr/bin/ruby -> /opt/omnybusruby/embedded/ruby-2/bin/ruby`.

If you have no internet access at all from the server is probably the best way to prepare the package on your laptop/system and deploy it on the remote.

Comment: Hey! Thank you, this might help, if I just had a repo to access any packages via yum.
Do you know any way to edit my repo to the repo of CentOS?

Comment: yum repositories are in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder, have a look here http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html is for centos 5 but should work.

Comment: Have you ever used CentOS or RedHat distributions ? What error you get ? is a bit difficult trying to help you with just "doesn't work" information :)

Comment: No. I'm sorry, but I never worked with RH-Distributions.
I just need to install Ruby on a VM that runs with RHEL.
I get the followin error:
No matter what I do, I allways get this error:

yum install example
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
No package available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: I have also replaced my redhat.repo replaced with the  kbsingh-CentOS-Extras.repo but nothing helps.
Even with this I get:

http://centos.karan.org/el6Server/extras/stable/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.karan.org/el6Server/extras/stable/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: kbs-CentOS-Extras. Please verify its path and try again

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Rails for the CodeReady Containers implementation of OpenShift in RHEL8/Cento8, using an OpenShift quickstart template. And in fact using rbenv now seems the cleanest way to install ruby:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install readline-devel openssl-devel
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
rbenv install -l
rbenv install 2.7.5
rbenv global 2.7.5
ruby -v
```